# Classify all abelian groups of order $2^4 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 11^3$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I know I can use the Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups, but that would be a total of $4 \cdot 2\cdot 3 = 24$ decompositions and simplifications, which would leave a lot of room for error. I was wondering if there is a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We obtain the abelian groups of order $2^4\cdot 5^2\cdot 11^3$ by
> taking one abelian group from each of the three lists(right-hand
> column below) and taking their direct product.

[image: Click here to zoom it]

Answer (score 5):

The group $\mathbb Z_{pqr\cdots}$ where $p,q,r\dots$ are pairwise coprime is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p×\mathbb Z_q×\mathbb Z_r×\cdots$ so we only need count the number of ways to partition each prime power into smaller prime powers. There are $5$ ways to decompose $2^4$ in this way, $2$ ways for $5^2$ and $3$ ways for $11^3$. Hence there are $5×2×3=30$ non-isomorphic groups of order $2^45^211^3$.

Comment: The [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_(number_theory)) also comes in handy.